# 301 permalink redirect htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched to no avail, hoping that someone can be my hero. I have 2 things going on.

I recently moved wordpress to the root folder and currently have the following redirect in my htaccess and all is working properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However, I have also changed my blog permalinks from /archives/post-id to /YY/MM/post-name. How can I implement the permalink redirect so I don't have to redirect each individual blog post? I have tried numerous different things with no luck. Also, where in particular should I paste the code in my file (above? below?) so as to not interfere and still work with the initial subdirectory to root redirect? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried searching "wordpress permalinks change"? The first result (from Yoast) seems promising...

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have. That tool only gives a code for changing your permalink structure to /post-name and I need to change to /YY/MM/post-name. I have also tried the Simple Redirect plugin that I found recommended on Google with no success. I literally Googled for HOURS yesterday and tried everything I found to no avail, which is why I eventually posted here. Thank you.

Comment: Currently what is happening is when someone clicks an old blog post it goes from http://www.website.com/blog/archives/1234 to http://www.website.com/archives/1234 as its removing the subdirectory which works for the pages on the site, but not the blog posts.

I need only the blog posts to go from /blog/archives/1234 to /yy/mm/post-name.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone ever wants to do something similar, I was able to make a slight modification and found something that worked for me.

I decided to change the permalinks from archives/post-id to archives/post-id/post-name.

To accomplish this I added the following code to my htaccess file above my #BEGIN Wordpress area...

```
# Redirect permalink archive/post-id to archive/post-id/post-name structure.
RedirectMatch 301 ^/archives/(\d+)$ http://www.website.com/archives/?p=$1
```